# What does "PDPN+ cells" means?

Tags: genetics, cell-biology, proteins, cell-membrane

Are they podoplanin positive cells (cells that tested positive for podoplanin)?

"...though it has been shown that podoplanin **(PDPN+) cells** analogous to mouse FRCs are found in human secondary lymphoid organs..." (https://journals.plos.org/plosbiology/article?id=10.1371/journal.pbio.2005046)

"Although rare, the few SFTPB+ observed in HLOs resemble AECII cells seen in the adult human lung, and **PDPN+ cells** resembled the elongated AECI cells in the human lung" "Few **PDPN+ cells** also showed elongated, squamous morphology seen in the adult lung." (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4370217/).

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please provide some context (for e.g. excerpt from the article/book which uses this term, with proper link)?

Comment: Yes, sure: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4370217/

Comment: James. We generally appreciate if a question is self sufficient. It is good that you provided a link but it would be even better if you could paste the exact sentence/paragraph that uses the term that you want to know. Use quotes or mark with a ">" in the beginning to indicate text that you have copied and pasted.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, that nomenclature means "cells which express PDPN"